# How to onClick copy text to clipboard from a <p> tag using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have.

```
<p class="right-side-header" title="Copy Text" id="text">I am cool</p>
```

Now the question is, what JavaScript will allow me to copy whatever text is in the `<p>` tag. I am new to JavaScript. I have no idea how to go about this.

How can I copy the `innerText` of the above element to the clipboard?

Comment: Have you searched?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=copy+text+clipboard+javascript

Comment: I've voted as Too Broad, but the [duplicate is probably this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/400212/472495).

Comment: I have searched but I didn't understand it. Im new to JS.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the same function from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53773474/10221765):

```js
function copyElementText(id) {
    var text = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
    var elem = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.value = text;
    elem.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<p class="right-side-header" title="Copy Text" id="text" onclick="copyElementText(this.id)">I am cool</p>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work on my tips page... wondering why.